# struts2, jsp project; show pdf

Tags: jsp, struts2, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I am try to show an pdf in jsp page without saving this in the hard disk. I was able to generate a pdf and I tested it by saving it in hard disk. I am using **DynamicJasper** as reporting engine.

Here is my strut.xml for dynamic-jasper:

```
<action name="myJasperTest" class="com.via.qcm.view.JasperAction">
  <result name="success" type="dynamic-jasper">
    <param name="dynamicReport">DynamicReport</param>
    <param name="layoutManager">classic</param>
    <param name="parameters">dynamicReportDs</param>
    <param name="documentName">report</param>
    <param name="contentDisposition">application/download</param>
    <param name="format">PDF</param>
  </result>
```

I am generating pdf and saving it in `ByteArrayOutputStream()`.

```
baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//export to pdf
Exporter.exportToPdf(jp, baos);
```

Now my question is how to show this "baos" in webpage as pdf?

Comment: Woah, accepted after 8 months, nice :] ... see you in 8 months from now for the upvote too :D

Comment: no man I actually did not know this feature of accept answer in that time. It was my first question in this website so please.. and I am sorry I dont have enough reputation to upvote :-(

Comment: Don't worry, just kidding ;) P.S: you *do* have the reputation to upvote... it is 15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

- you need to return a `DynamicReport` object, not an `Byte Array`;
- the dynamicReport variable must start with a `lowercase` letter:

In `Struts.xml`

```
    <param name="dynamicReport">dynamicReport</param>
```

In the `Action`

```
public DynamicReport getDynamicReport(){
    DynamicReport dynamicReport = null;
    // do all your stuff
    return dynamicReport;
}
```